# Is linux's "load average" comparable to Windows' "processor time"?

Tags: linux, monitoring

is there is a way for monitoring the linux server's processor.?  i found

```
cat /proc/loadavg
```

command in ssh. it returns the results as

```
0.07 0.26 0.23 1/156 3832
```

is this load average in linux  is same as the processor time in windows ....?

if not please suggest some command for getting the processor time of linux system...

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell, the [load](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_%28computing%29) is the average of the number of processes waiting for processor time over the last 1, 5 and 15 minutes, whereas the [processor time](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12984.understanding-processor-processor-time-and-process-processor-time.aspx) in Windows is the percentage of the time the processor spends actually doing things (e.g. not idling).

You can get a live overview of percentages with the `top` command.

Comment: To get at system stats including detailed cpu stats (system, user, idle, wait) use vmstat in a console.